# Relieving on Sunday (Being Holiday)

Tags: job-change

I want to relieve on sunday 25/10/2014. Can my employer relieve me
on sunday i.e. 25/10/2014 after giving salary for 3 months towards
notice period.

Comment: Hello and welcome to The Workplace.  Questions about what is legal, or about policies of your company, are off-topic here; we aren't lawyers and people not familiar with your company can't address its policies.  Your best bet is to ask your HR department or manager about this.  Thanks for understanding, and good luck in your job change.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I assume by your terminology that you are talking about India. I am not familiar with the intricacies of Indian employment law but I have worked with and managed people from India. What follows is my understanding but, as usual, there is no substitute for qualified legal advice.

I assume by "relieve" you mean have your employment terminated. In other words, you want your last day to be a Sunday.

The idea of a notice period is to give you adequate time to find a new job or, failing that, control your spending so you have time to do so. Similarly, it gives the company time to train a replacement, change processes or otherwise cope with the loss of a staff member.

Most countries have a mandated minimum (Australia, most of Europe) or convention (USA). Three months, however sounds like a long time, which should be more than long enough to cater for this.

Is it possible to do on a Sunday? If you regularly work on Sundays then it makes sense. If you do not, it will probably best be a day of the week you regularly work. An employee's last day usually involves signing forms, handing back computers, surrendering access passes, exit interviews and other administrative work (not to mention a farewell lunch with your team). That usually requires other staff to be present but they may not be on a Sunday.

Assuming you have at least a reasonable level of trust with your management, you should be able to work out something that works for both you and your organization. It may have to be the preceding Friday or following Monday. If you are unsure, talk to your HR and your boss.